# Tableau Dashboard Templating

Tags: tableau-api

How can we make the Tableau dashboard templated? We would like to create just the template/wireframe of our reports and as the client requests we should be able to fetch that specific data and generate the report and display it to the client on tableau embedded-web?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a good way to do this, but there are some hacky workarounds.

## Option 1: Separate DB Servers for each Client, Same Schema

If each client has a separate database server with the same schema, you can use the [Tableau Server REST API](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_ref_datasources.htm) to duplicate the workbook and data source for each client, then use the Update Data Source Connection endpoint to change the database server the data source points to to the new client's.

## Option 2: Same Database Server and Schema

1. Create a column in your database table named 'client' and set it to the client's ID or client's name in all of your rows
2. Create a parameter in your Tableau workbook named "Client"
3. When connecting to the database and table in Tableau, you can use a custom SQL statement such as:
   `SELECT * FROM table WHERE client=<Parameters.Client>`
4. Once you have the workbook loaded, you can use the JS API method [Workbook.changeParameterValueAsync()](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api_ref.htm#workbook_class) method to set the Client parameter to the appropriate client ID

*This has some critical security issues:* If the user is able to figure out the client ID of another client, they can get their data. They can also brute force this by calling changeParameterValueAsync themselves.

Comment: Thanks so much Luke for your solution. Let me give you our scenario.We'll be having huge set of data (may be in spreadsheet stored in S3 or in DB) for around 10K universities across the world and each university will have around 20 sets of analytics data(in spreadsheet or DB).We are leaning towards storing datasets for each universities in its own S3 bucket.A user can come in and request a report for any of these 10K universities and can also apply some filters.We need generate and display reports for the requested university dynamically.Please advise.

Comment: I see. If you stick the data in S3, you could look at using Athena and the Tableau Athena data connector. This way you could keep adding data/universities to your S3 bucket and Tableau could keep picking up the new data.

Comment: Thank again Luke, using Tableau Athena data connector i can get data from S3 but i am still confused about dynamically generating the Dashboard/Reports as the user selects/enter the university name.Does Tableau allows to create dashboard/report template and fill in the data dynamically based on the user input?

Comment: You would use the university name column as a filter, this way only the selected university's data is shown.